# Fastest string find from the list of string

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, stl

I have a list of strings and I have to find whether a string is present in that list or not. I wanted to use the logic in low latency pricing engine so I wanted to have real fast logic for it.
I thought of having these strings stored in map as keys and then could use find() or count() function for the same. 
Can anyone suggest any other more efficient logic for the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) is an appropriate choice for your needs. You would then use `find()` to check if a string is present or not. Something like the [example code here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/find/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

int main() {

  std::unordered_set<std::string> myset{ "red", "green", "blue" };

  std::cout << "color? ";
  std::string input;
  std::cin >> input;

  auto pos = myset.find(input);

  if (pos != myset.end())
    std::cout << *pos << " is in myset\n";
  else
    std::cout << "not found in myset\n";

}
```

To understand how `std::unordered_set` works, please see [hash set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Comment: yes Ali, my code is a c++ code. I have just added the pseudo code for the logic.

Comment: That 100% answers my question. I also found out that my strfind() way of doing is also not efficient as well... since its slower traditional C way of string manipulation..

Comment: @BhupeshPant OK, I am glad it helped. I have added a little example code.

Comment: what would be you suggestion in case we have integers without any duplicate entry? Data structure wise I would say normal binary tree would do. but which stl class should be used? I am  completely new to STL world so I am sorry if I am asking some very basic questions.

Comment: @BhupeshPant It also depends on how you use it. Either `unordered_set<int>` or a sorted `vector<int>` with `lower_bound()`. If you want to a tree, then `set<int>`, although that is probably the slowest wrt lookup.

Comment: @BhupeshPant You might want to look at [Using map in conjunction with vector and cache impact](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19134358/341970).

Comment: Thanks Ali. I haven't investigate on which would be the best for me. For string I am sure that unordered_set is the best choice but I am still not sure on int. I want a DS that uses B-tree because the list of the data would be fixed and would be easier if I store them in some order. But I am not sure what ds vector uses and does it store the data in sorted manner? I am sure, as per my knowledge the set and map does that but it would be probably easy and more readable to use vector for my case, thats why I am more curious about vector..

Comment: @BhupeshPant `std::vector` doesn't order the elements for you, you have to write the necessary code yourself. That's why I suggested that you use `boost::container::flat_map` which is essentially just a sorted vector BUT all the necessary functions are written for you, you don't have to write it yourself. Please read my answer at [Using map in conjunction with vector and cache impact](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19134358/341970) about the potential pitfalls.

Answer (score -2):

One more way I just now thought of is,

Put the list of string in single semicolon separated string and then use strfind.

e.g.

```
List of string, <ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,MNO,PQRS,LMNOPQR, STUVW,XY,Z>
l_czEIDHolder = “ABC;DEF;GHI;JKL;MNO;PQRS;LMNOPQR; STUVW;XY;Z”
if  string_to_search = “PQRS”
make string_to_search = string_to_search +”;”
strfind(czEIDHolder, string_to_search) OR
string::find(czEIDHolder, string_to_search)
```

Comment: -1 Convoluted solution. That fails if your search string contains your proposed delimiter (semicolon). Plus, since you were asking for *fast*, *slow* is not an answer (O(1) vs. O(n)).

Comment: For that I am sure that It will not contains that delimiter. I will only take your second point for (-1).. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Also fails, if your search string matches the tail end (but not the entire string). This is not a solution.

Comment: Accepted all your point.But all your points come into consideration after the fact that I will choose this way. C is very bad in handling string. All the string functions that C offers are not at all considered as efficient. Thats why we have std::string to effectively handle string operations as other language do. So choice of having he above solution is already ruled out and if you have read my main intention, is to achieve efficiency. Thanks for your findings. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `std::string` is implemented in terms of the C string handling functions. C++ is, if anything, **less** efficient. You need to get familiar with a profiler. Even if it were faster this answer proposes a slow algorithm. Lookup with an `unordered_set` is amortized constant time on average, worst case linear time. Your lookup is always linear time. Of course this can be further optimized by not using a string as an ID. String comparisons are inherently slow, when compared to integer comparisons.